# How can I see Site Stats?

Tags: discussion

After official launch of Ask Different we loose little "site stats" box:

[image]

Know how can we see Ask Different stats?
I check [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/151/apple) it seems that the stats didn't update after official launch.
Also I check [data.stackexchamge.com](http://data.stackexchange.com/) and realize that Ask Different didn't add there yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://api.apple.stackexchange.com/1.0/stats

Its not very user friendly, but the data is there.

Answer (score 6):

You can see the site stats for all of our sites here: http://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: I saw that but it has not full detail, such as exact number of member, number of visitor/day not visits/day, number of comment, number of tags and ...

Comment: @Am1rr3za Some of those statistics weren't even shown in the beta Site Stats box.  And if you want exact numbers for the stats shown on http://stackexchange.com/sites you can hover over the numbers and wait for the tooltip.

Comment: @Am1rr3za There's also a link on the stackexchange.com/sites page that takes you to another version of the site list with expanded statistics: http://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true

Comment: @gcla Tanx nice info.

Answer (score 4):

Moderators have access to detailed analytics but these are not meant to be shared too widely.